# Delete em 2 tabelas ao mesmo tempo em uma só query

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte **query**:

```
DELETE FROM emails,emailsacompanhamento 
USING emails,emailsacompanhamento 
WHERE emails.idEmail = emailsacompanhamento.idEmail AND 
emails.idEmail = ".$idEmail
```

Que faz uma espécie de `JOIN` em 2 **tabelas** e **deleta** em *ambas* de uma só vez.

Tudo funciona bem. Mas preciso criar uma condicional que diz que:

se na tabela ***emailsacompanhamento*** não houver nenhum registro cujo campo `idEmail` seja igual ao `idEmail` da tabela **Emails** referenciado na **query**, a consulta delete o registro da tabela **Emails** e desconsidera a tabela ***emailsacompanhamento***.

Como seria essa **query**?

Comment: Se na tabela `emailsacompanhamento` não tiver registros, deleto somente o registro da tabela `emails` ou não faço nada? Isso ficou um pouco confuso pra mim.

Comment: Deleta somente o registro na tabela emails

Comment: E se houver registros na tabela `emailsacompanhamento `? Deleta as duas?

Comment: Ja utilizou o drop cascate?

Comment: Isso, se houver o e-mail e não houver a companhamento deleta só o e-mail. E se houver os dois deleta tudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `DELETE` com `JOIN`, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$sql = "
    DELETE emails, emailsacompanhamento FROM `emails`
    LEFT JOIN `emailsacompanhamento ` ON `emails`.`idEmail` = `emailsacompanhamento `.`idEmail`
    WHERE `emails`.`idEmail` = ".$idEmail;
```

**Edit**

No `SELECT` você define quais campo serão retornados antes do `FROM`, exemplo: `SELECT campo1, campo2... FROM sua_tabela`. Já no caso do `DELETE` você não pode deletar um campo especifico, ou deleta tudo ou não deleta nada.

Em um `DELETE` simples, você não precisa informar a tabela antes do `FROM`, ficando assim:

```
DELETE FROM sua_tabela WHERE campo1 = value1;
```

Mas quando o `DELETE` é composto por `JOIN` é necessário informar quais tabelas terão o registro removido caso a condição retorne `True`. Essas tabelas estarão antes do `FROM` como por exemplo:

```
DELETE tabela1 FROM tabela1
INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.campo1 = tabela2.campo2
```

No exemplo acima, somente os registros da tabela `tabela1` serão removidos caso a verificação `tabela1.campo1 = tabela2.campo2` seja `True`.

Comment: FROM `curso`??? não entendi

Comment: Alterei, foi a tabela que fiz teste aqui, malz.

Comment: deu certo aqui, obrigado. Só não entendi isso: DELETE emails, emailsacompanhamento FROM `emails`. Como pode o nomes das tabelas funcionarem como atributos?

Comment: Isso porque você não consegue deletar somente algumas colunas das tabelas ou deleta a linha inteira ou não deleta nada. Se a resposta resolveu seu problema de um `upvote` e sinalize como sendo a solução da pergunta.

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se dessa forma é possível compreender melhor.

Comment: entendi: muiiiiito bem explicado! Obrigado!